# Removing .php from URL Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My site directory structure as follows:

```
/var/www/html/wordpress/
/var/www/html/rail/
```

`/wordpress/` is my default site when `www.example.com` is accessed. Wordpress contains `.htaccess` automatically made by wp.

`/rail/` is an alias inside apache `sites-enabled` and is accessible at `www.example.com/rail`

File contents inside `/rail/` have file extension `.php`, but this is shown in the address bar which I do not want, for user experience purposes.
I would like `/rail/search/(future)/search/parameters/`
Instead of `/rail/search.php/future/search/parameters/`

I have read other stack overflow support topics about nanoing the `.htaccess` but my `htaccess` is inside `wordpress`.
Will I need to create another .htaccess inside /rail/?

What would be the best way to remove `.php` file `exension` from .php files, so that my URL structure is seamless, like wordpress, and not get the awkward .php?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can added  your code in .htaccess created by wordpress. But instead create another .htaccess file in rail directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes made in you VirtualHost(apache) file, where in you where using an alias.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
Alias /rail "/var/www/html/rail"
<Directory "/var/www/html/rail">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Use the following code to remove .php extension from url for `/rail/` directory by creating .htaccess file in `/rail/` directory.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rail/

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry but its not making any difference.
Ive created a file .htaccess in /var/www/html/rail/ with the above and rebooted server/restarted apache2 service and /rail/search comes as 404 not found.
Eager to get this resolved, happy to supply root access to server if needed?

Comment: Yes, you can email it to my id shameem.sam@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you, I have sent login details by email please let me know if you have not received and I will resend.

Comment: Hey there, did you find the solution for you question. And I haven't received any email from you.

Comment: No I haven't found a solution yet. I will resend the email now, as it may have gone to spam :)